# ERROR. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this code for my layout with **RecyclerView**

```
package com.josue.snapshots

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.josueproyects.snapshots.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import com.josueproyects.snapshots.databinding.ItemSnapshotBinding
import com.josueproyects.snapshots.snapshot.Snapshot

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var mFirebaseAdapter: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Snapshot,SnapshotHoler>
    private lateinit var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        mBinding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        return mBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference //es la raiz
            .child("snapshot") //es la rama
        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Snapshot>()
            .setQuery(query,Snapshot::class.java).build()

        mFirebaseAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Snapshot,SnapshotHoler>(options){
            private lateinit var mContext: Context
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SnapshotHoler {
                mContext = parent.context //declarar el contexto
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_snapshot,parent,false)
                return SnapshotHoler(view)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SnapshotHoler, position: Int, model: Snapshot) {
                val snapshot = getItem(position)

                with(holder){
                    setListener(snapshot)
                    with(binding){
                        tvTitle.text = snapshot.title

                        Glide.with(mContext)
                            .load(snapshot.photoUrl)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(imgPhoto)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onDataChanged() {
                super.onDataChanged()
                mBinding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            override fun onError(error: DatabaseError) {
                super.onError(error)
                Toast.makeText(mContext, error.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) //el tipo de vista que se vera (sera de forma LinearLayout)

        mBinding.recyclerView.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = mLayoutManager
            adapter = mFirebaseAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mFirebaseAdapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening()
    }

    //holder del snapshot (para el recycler view)
    inner class SnapshotHoler(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val binding = ItemSnapshotBinding.bind(view)

        fun setListener(snapshot: Snapshot){

        }
    }
}
```

But it shows me this error:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionSnapshotHoler{15a1686 position=1 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{123fd4a VFED..... .......D 0,0-1080,1437 #7f080163 app:id/recyclerView}, adapter:com.josueproyects.snapshots.HomeFragment$onViewCreated$1@4bb94bb, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@ed17dd8, context:com.josue.snapshots.MainActivity@9d9a2fd
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:6156)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6339)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4255)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4010)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:2028)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:417)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The project consists of uploading data to Firebase, when I enter the app everything goes well, but when I am in the Add frangment, I click an **ImageButton** to open the phone gallery, I select the photo and show it, but when show it in the layout I get the error, I know it has to do with the RecyclerView but... What do I do?.

Comment: Where is the error line?

Comment: Is `imgPhoto` in your view holder? I don't see it defined.